# How to export the full Sphinx (TOC) tree to a file?

Tags: json, xml, python-sphinx

I am working on a tool which converts **the exported HTML Sphinx** documentation into PDF. The main issue comes with the structure of the PDF, without the TOC tree there is no easy way to know which index.html should go after the other, and build a logical PDF.

Is there a way to get the whole tree somehow, with infinite depth, and export it, XML, JSON...?
Doing it manually is quite crazy since the documentation is very big and is constantly growing.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Why would you do this instead of use Sphinx's ability to build latex then PDF from the source reST files?

Comment: Could be done, but it has been discarded: We developed a customized version of Sphinx to tweak doxygen since the project includes documentation of a custom programming language, not supported out of the box. Tweaking the LaTeX functionality would be redoing all the work. Additionally, all the styling has been made already for the HTML, maintaining also the LaTeX templates would also be double work. Going for the HTML to PDF seems like the best option for this case.

Comment: Perhaps you can use the `singlehtml` builder. http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/man/sphinx-build.html#cmdoption-sphinx-build-b

Comment: Thanks @mzjn, will give it a try. Still, there is really no way to get the full TOC as a (env) variable or something?

Comment: @mzjn Again thank you very much! I tried the `singlehtml` and indeed works but the problem is that it increases so much the build time that it makes kind of impossible to work locally to test. Using `singlehtml` to build the PDFs means building 1 time for the documentation and `n-times` for each desired PDF, which can lead to building time of hours. I have been digging the sphinx library but still I do not manage to get the full tree...which seems impossible! Any thoughts?

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. I managed using a quite ugly solution but does the job: I edited the `layout.html` and included a hidden full toctree using `<div style="display: none !important;"id="full_toctree">{{ toctree(maxdepth=-1|toint, collapse=False,includehidden=True|tobool) }}</div>`. This way, I can inspect the output HTML and fetch the entire toctree to later on pass it to my PDF generator. Hope it helps others!